# Simple FileUpload with php doesn't work

Tags: php, file-upload

I Have this code:

```
$filename=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$extension=explode(".", $filename);
$newfilename=$rezeptID .".".$extension;


      if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"] . "<br />";
        }
      else
        {
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] . "<br />";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] . "<br />";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

        if (file_exists("/Images/Rezepte/" . $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
          move_uploaded_file($filename,
          "/Images/Rezepte/" . $newfilename);
          echo "Stored in: " . "/Images/Rezepte/" .$newfilename;
          }
        }
```

The variable $rezeptinfo is just a number and is correct, if you wonder.

When I now submit my form, I get this info about the file:

"Upload: 
Type: 
Size: 0 Kb
Temp file: 
Stored in: /Images/Rezepte/10."

Why are the extension of the file and all the basic information mssing. 10 is the value of $rezeptID. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

first, your way of getting the extension returns an array and so cant be concatenated to a string, you need to specify the index of the array where the extension is which is 1 :

```
$newfilename=$rezeptID .".".$extension[1];
```

or

```
$newfilename=$rezeptID .".".end($extension);
```

or

```
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

also, u should the move the uploaded file from the temp_file path

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],"Images/" .$newfilename);
```

You should also ensure that **enctype="multipart/form-data"** is included in your html form property